# Shifting functions to minimise the maximum variance accross a domain.

Tags: statistics

Assume we have a family of $N$ continuous functions $f_i(x)\in C_\infty$ along domain $D$.

Define a set of constants $c_i \in  \mathbb{R}$ and define the functions $g_i(x)$ so each $g_i(x)$.
\begin{equation}
 g_i(x) = f_i(x) + c_i
\end{equation}
The mean of the functions $g_i$ at $x$ is denoted $\mu_g(x)$

\begin{equation}
 \mu_g(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (g_i(x))
\end{equation}

We define the variance of $g_i(x)$ using the following:
\begin{equation}
 Var_g(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (g_i(x) - \mu_g(x))^2
\end{equation}
Our goal is to find the set of constants $c_i$ to minimise the quantity.
\begin{equation}
\max_{x \in D} \{ (Var_g(x)) \} 
\end{equation}

What is a reasonable strategy for finding the set of $c_i$'s?